# In Drools Rules, how to use two different ArrayList objects,obj1 is used in rule 1 and obj2 used in rule2?

Tags: list, object, rules, drools

I am doing ksession.insert(list) and after that I have to fire rule 1 in the drl file, then ksession.insert(list) and fire rule 2 in the drl.

Could someone tell me how to achieve this. I read about agenda filters and facthandles but do not really know how to get this to work

Below is some code:

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add(product1);
list.add(product2);
list.add(product3);

ksession.insert(list);
ksession.fireAllRules("fire rule 1 in drl");

//remove list?

ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
list2.add(str1);
list2.add(str2);
list2.add(str3);

ksession.insert(list2); 
ksession.fireAllRules("fire rule 2 in drl");

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a better workaround...you can control pattern matching..

Here is a simple and quick way

```
arrayList1.add("Rule 1");//if you can afford this without generics
arrayList1.add(...);//everything else you want to add
arrayList2.add("Rule 2");
arrayList2.add(..);//rest...

..
ksession.insert(..) ;//insert everything one by one
```

..
in your drl and inside Rule  1
..when you want Rule 1 to work with arraylist1, have this matching first in the lhs
`$al:ArrayList(this contains "Rule 1")`

That is all..

Answer (score 0):

You don't directly control what rules fire - the constraints on the rules determine this. Filters can only help if you are stopping rules from firing.